# Production Mode app:config:import issue

Tags: magento2, database, configuration, deployment

after a new deployment I get the following error:

```
{"0":"The configuration file has changed. Run app:config:import or setup:upgrade command to synchronize configuration.","1":"#0 \/var\/www\/dev.xxx.com\/httpdocs\/releases\/4\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\\Deploy\\Model\\Plugin\\ConfigChangeDetector->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#1 \/var\/www\/dev.xxx.com\/httpdocs\/releases\/4\/vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/App\/FrontController\/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#2 \/var\/www\/dev.xxx.com\/httpdocs\/releases\/4\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\FrontController\\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#3 \/var\/www\/dev.xxx.com\/httpdocs\/releases\/4\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#4 \/var\/www\/dev.xxx.com\/httpdocs\/releases\/4\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#5 \/var\/www\/dev.xxx.com\/httpdocs\/releases\/4\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(135): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#6 \/var\/www\/dev.xxx.com\/httpdocs\/releases\/4\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#7 \/var\/www\/dev.xxx.com\/httpdocs\/releases\/4\/pub\/index.php(37): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#8 {main}","url":"\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

But when I run bin/magento app:config:import (irrelevant how often) it says  `Nothing to import.`

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue - the solution for me was clearing the opcache.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying to solve this for like hours. And a "systemctl restart httpd" (which clears the opcache if mod_php is used) fixed it. :/

Answer (score -1):

**Production Mode app:config:import issue**

- Error are come to change `app/etc/config.php` file.
- Again import your configurations file from `app/etc/config.php` your database

  Run run below command

  `php bin/magento app:config:import`

Please review [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-config-mgmt-import.html)

Comment: Hmm I don't understand this. Because I wrote execute app:config:import doesn't change anything...

Comment: please review this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-config-mgmt-import.html